# Using php.net's password_verify" script as offered works, but fails if hash is read back from DB

Tags: php, passwords, php-password-hash

php.net script: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
and: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

The apparent simplicity of this password verification routine is very appealing, but after a day of reading at stackoverflow and innumerable hacks, here is my very simple, not-at-all-secure, testing version:

```
<?php

$p = "bumblebee";
$hash =  (password_hash($p, PASSWORD_DEFAULT));

echo ($p);
echo ($hash);

if (password_verify('bumblebee', $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
    } else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
    }

?>
```

ABOVE RETURNS 'Password is valid!' (this is two scripts from PHP.net combined)

BELOW DOES NOT WORK (only diff is the hash is written to DB and read back, then converted to a string)

```
<?php

$userName = $_REQUEST["userName"];
$passWord = $_REQUEST["passWord"];

// $p = "$passWord";
// $hash =  (password_hash($p, PASSWORD_DEFAULT));

    //set DB access variables
    require_once('./php/hs_DBlogin.php');

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $passWord_get = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT passWordHash FROM hsUser WHERE userName='$userName' LIMIT 1");
    $passWord_out = mysqli_fetch_array($passWord_get);
    $hashAsStr = $passWord_out[0];

    echo ($hashAsStr);
    echo ($_REQUEST["passWord"]);


if (password_verify($_REQUEST["passWord"], $hashAsStr)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
    } else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
    }

?>

Here is the insert to DB script:

// Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$passWordHash = password_hash('$passWord', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


$sql = "INSERT INTO `hsUser`(`firstName`, `lastName`, `userName`, `passWordHash`,`hsStatus`) VALUES ('$firstName','$lastName','$userName','$passWordHash','$hsStatus')";
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, it's a security risk to use `$_REQUEST` for login operations. You're making it easier to try passwords AND allowing URLs to be stored in the client's browser history. Use `$_POST` only for sensitive stuff like this

Comment: Are you sure the whole hash fits into the passwordhash field?

Comment: Perhaps consider showing how the password was entered and stored in the database in the first place

Comment: As @MarkBaker said, we'd need to see how you're storing the password and how you've configured the table. [For instance, is the column size for the password 60 or greater?](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) If not you will never be able to compare with `password_verify()` to confirm.

Comment: mysql field is set to char(255)

Comment: here's center of insert script:

Comment: thanks to: @MarkBaker and Machavity// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$passWordHash = password_hash('$passWord', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


$sql = "INSERT INTO `hsUser`(`firstName`, `lastName`, `userName`, `passWordHash`,`hsStatus`) VALUES ('$firstName','$lastName','$userName','$passWordHash','$hsStatus')";

Comment: I am probalby using this comment field wrong - will learn

Comment: I added the insert script to the end of the original question

Comment: Check that `passWordHash` field in the database has **AT LEAST** 30 characters of longitude, and its type is `VARCHAR`

Comment: @Condorcho - A BCrypt hash contains 60 characters, so a field of 30 characters is too short. To be future proof, it is recommended to be of type `varchar(255)`.

Comment: @martinstoeckli That's why I typed at least. Using `password_hash` with `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` returns a hash of 30 characters.

Comment: Yes, you're right, just checked it. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Gave up on php's password_verify and used sha1
script at:
http://www.localwisdom.com/blog/2013/03/building-a-simple-registerlogin-system-in-php-using-sha256/
after some clean-up, works fine

Answer (score 0):

Please don't give up so fast, your alternative method using SHA256 is an extremely unsafe method to store your user's passwords.

As others already mentioned, it is recommended to use a `varchar(255)` field. According to your comments this is not the problem though.

If the code you are showing for the registration is exactly your working code, then the culprit is very likely this line:

```
$passWordHash = password_hash('$passWord', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

This statement will create a hash of the text `'$passWord'` and not from the variable `$passWord`, so instead it should be:

```
$passWordHash = password_hash($passWord, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```